# Org-export: Convenient input/pasting of style information with many lines

Tags: org-export

When exporting an Org buffer to HTML, how can I inject a `<style>`-tag with many lines of contents into the **head** of the HTML document?

I know `#+HTML_HEAD:` and `#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA:`. But that prefix must be added to all contents lines.

I also know about `#+BEGIN_EXPORT html`...`#+END_EXPORT`.  But the contents of those blocks end up in the body of the HTML document.

Comment: Why have the style sheet explicitly in the org file? Why not create a style sheet file and then override/add to the default style sheet the way the documentation suggests:
`#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />
     #+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css" />`?

Comment: @NickD Sometimes that is just the way it is and one has to live with it. In my case the HTML file is the embedded documentation of a Modelica type and that type can be moved around within [`MODELICAPATH`](http://doc.simulationx.com/4.0/1033/Content/10_Modelica/Modeling%20with%20the%20Modelica%20Standard%20Library.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I did not yet find a standard way.

So I added an attribute `:head` to HTML export blocks.
If that attribute is set to `t` or `yes` the contents of the export block ends up in the `<head>` of the HTML document.

```el
(defun org+-html-export-block (fun export-block contents info)
  "Take the \"head\" export attribute for EXPORT-BLOCK into account.
This is an around advice for `org-html-export-block'.
If the EXPORT-BLOCK has the head attribute
put its contents into the :html-head property of INFO."
  (when (string= (org-element-property :type export-block) "HTML")
    (let ((attributes (org-export-read-attribute :attr_html export-block)))
      (if (member (plist-get attributes :head) '("t" "yes"))
      (progn
        (plist-put info :html-head
               (org-remove-indentation (org-element-property :value export-block)))
        nil)
    (funcall fun export-block contents info)))))

(advice-add 'org-html-export-block :around #'org+-html-export-block)
```

Example Org document:

```
#+OPTIONS: html-style:nil html-scripts:nil
#+TITLE: Test for Org export blocks

* This is a test for Org Export Blocks.
Some block that ends up in the body:
#+BEGIN_EXPORT html
<p>This paragraph comes from the export block.</p>
#+END_EXPORT

Another block that ends up in the head:
#+ATTR_HTML: :head t
#+BEGIN_EXPORT html
<style>
p {
  color: red;
}
</style>
#+END_EXPORT
```

The generated HTML buffer:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<!-- 2020-03-27 Fri 16:05 -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Test for Org export blocks</title>
<meta name="generator" content="Org mode" />
<style>
p {
  color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<h1 class="title">Test for Org export blocks</h1>
<div id="table-of-contents">
<h2>Table of Contents</h2>
<div id="text-table-of-contents">
<ul>
<li><a href="#org27bee3e">1. This is a test for Org Export Blocks.</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="outline-container-org27bee3e" class="outline-2">
<h2 id="org27bee3e"><span class="section-number-2">1</span> This is a test for Org Export Blocks.</h2>
<div class="outline-text-2" id="text-1">
<p>
Some block that ends up in the body:
</p>
<p>This paragraph comes from the export block.</p>

<p>
Another block that ends up in the head:
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="postamble" class="status">
<p class="date">Created: 2020-03-27 Fri 16:05</p>
<p class="validation"><a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">Validate</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```